# cruisecontrol.net integration with TFS2012

Tags: tfs, cruisecontrol.net

I want to integrate cruisecontrol.net with TFS2012, but there is no plugins available for  TFS2012. Please explain the steps I need to take.

Answer (score 0):

CruiseControl includes a plug-in to download source code from TFS Version Control.

http://cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Team_Foundation_Server_(Tfs)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but sir there is no plug-ins available on this link, it'shows 404 Error, when i try to open that link

http://cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Visual_Studio_Team_Foundation_Server_Plugin

Will you please help me to provide latest TFS2012 plugins for cruise control

Comment: "includes" a plug-in.  It's already there.  You just have to wire it up.

Comment: Sorry but i am not getting you, what you are trying to say, will you please create that plugings for me?? i mean will you please wire it up?? so i can download and i will use that?

please do it for me it's very urgent for me, please sir